# Database Design: Confused with data

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, relational-database

I have weather data in Excel for 3 countries: UK, France and Sweden. The data is for each day through an year so that is 366 rows per country.

The unique identifier is that the date. For example, all the countries share the same date as "01/04/2012"  just different information for it.

First I created 3 different tables for each country, but I figured this way I still repeat the same date and I will have to search through different tables late implementing in the web system.

Now I figured to put all the data in one table and adding id and country columns, but that generates even more data and its 1100 rows long which might slow down my system later at implementation.

Can you advise me how can I design it so each date is referenced to its own country and data  but not repeating the date all the time? Maybe some foreign key ... ?

Comment: Well, there could be different approaches depending on the scaling you would need. For the time being, I would suggest simply putting countries in columns aswell as the date. So for 1 row (=1 date), you would have the data for all countries.

Comment: @Bartdude I have 22 other columns of data for each date and generating the database through my apache server with sqlite took a long time. That is what scared me.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize there were that much columns. Then indeed you shouldn't put it all in the same table. Then you're left with 2 choices I'd say : the approach you first had, with the inconvenience that you may need to join tables to gather info from all countries (and aleter several tables if you need to add a 23rd value), or the answer from DhruvJoshi

Comment: @Bartdude I was thinking of 2 Tables: `Data`, containing the data, and `Indexes`, containing `Country`, `Country id`, `Date` and `Date id`. Then refer to the table `Data` with `Country id` and  `Date id` as a foreign key. But then my concern is again with the implementation with PHP, AJAX, etc. How would i join the tables and wouldn't join introduce issues when using the database. 

`P.S You can refer to the link with the data spreadsheet link i have posted in the comments of DhruvJoshi so you can visualize it.`

Comment: Well, if you need to store extra data about countries, then you would need a "countries" table with a primary key (was it and id or the country ISO code) and when referring to the country in other table, use this key. About the date though, you probably won't need extra data so you can use a date field wherever you would need it. If I can add 1 more thing : don't be too worried about repeating information. It is not a problem. For example if it's 25°C several days in a row, you will not store a "reference" to a record in a "temparature" table, you will simply put the data as such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the way for better design should be a single table with country and date as a composite key.

This will not slow down your system, as you can build index on the Country and Date columns.

From a normalized system point of view, a better idea would be to have a table Countries with an `[CountryId]` column and `[Country Name]` column.

This `[CountryId]` will be put in as a FK reference in your main data table.

Comment: A primary key on {Country, Date} will automatically create an index in every SQL dbms I can think of. Adding a separate table with a country ID number has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Catcall' - yes not repeating the words 'USA' or 'SWEDEN' by creating a new table with a country and id is exactly normalization.

Comment: [link] https://www.mediafire.com/?i53d4jai127yrxh There is my excel spreadsheet with the data. So you can have a better view of how can i do it or should i normalize at all.

Comment: as the country symbol is already normative and most people know them, I would use this as CountryId. Then you do not need a country table. Is the link  above spam?

Comment: @sqlab No! The link is my personal storage at mediafire and as you can see it contains an xlsx file which means it's an excel spreadsheet. You can even review it online if you do not want to download it.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi But in that way won't I introduce more repetitiveness of the date field now? As it would go `Country id(e.g. uk = 1) -> date/data/data; Country id(e.g. sweden =2) -> samedate/data/data;`

Answer (score 0):

you would have a country table

```
country
--------
country_id
name
```

and a weather table

```
weather
----------
observation_date
country_id
observation
```

Answer (score 0):

A table like this

```
iso_country_code  observation_date  observation
--
GBR               2014-02-01        Clear
FRA               2014-02-01        Light rain
SWE               2014-02-01        Scattered clouds
GBR               2014-02-02        Snow
FRA               2014-02-02        Overcast
SWE               2014-02-02        Mostly cloudy
GBR               2014-02-03        Clear
FRA               2014-02-03        Snow
SWE               2014-02-03        Snow
```

has only one non-trivial functional dependency.

```
{iso_country_code, observation_date}->observation
```

The set of columns {iso_country_code, observation_date} is the only candidate key. This table is in 6NF. No guideline of normalization can raise it to a higher normal form.

**An example of improvement**

As it stands, the SQL statement `INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('SWF', '2014-02-04', 'Snow');` will commit successfully, even though 'SWF' is clearly a typo. (No country has the ISO country code 'SWF'.)

You can increase data integrity for the column iso_country_code by creating a table of valid country codes, and setting a foreign key reference to it.  If you were using SQL, for example, you might do it like this.

```
create table iso_country_codes (
  iso_country_code char(3) primary key,
  iso_country_name varchar(30) not null unique
);

insert into iso_country_codes values
('GBR', 'United Kingdom'),
('FRA', 'France'),
('SWE', 'Sweden');

alter table weather
add constraint 
foreign key (iso_country_code) references iso_country_codes (iso_country_code);
```

This has *nothing* to do with normalization. There are lots of aspects of database design that have nothing to do with normalization.